# Conan package losing file rights

Tags: conan

I'm creating a package from a precompiled library (Zip file).
The Zip file have a file named codegen which have executable rights (-rwxr-xr-x).
But when I check the conan package I have only read rights (-rw-r--r--).

I checked the copy methode from conan but ther is no parameter for something like this.

Here my conanfile.py

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools


class external-libConan(ConanFile):
    name = "external-ib"
    version = "0.6.0"
    license = "<Put the package license here>"
    author = "me"
    url = "<Package recipe repository url here, for issues about the package>"
    description = "<Description of external-lib here>"
    topics = ("<Put some tag here>", "<here>", "<and here>")
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"

    def build(self):
        url = ("http://url/external-lib.zip")
        tools.get(url)

        self.run("cp -R external-lib/* ./")
        self.run("rm -rf external-lib")

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*")

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.builddirs = ["", "lib/cmake/external-lib"]
```

Does anyone know how to copy file rights into the conan package?

Comment: Conan uses the same user to download. Are your using Docker or some shared folder in your home folder, which may be affect by another user?

Comment: Did you try to set `tools.get(url, keep_permissions=True)`

Comment: There is no shared folder or Docker.
I removed the ```self.run("rm -rf external-lib")``` command and checked the permissions in the extracted folder. They are correct. I think the ```self.copy("*")```  command lost the premissions.